# Get hours, minutes, seconds from Moment.js object

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I wonder if it is possible to fetch hours, minutes and seconds from Moment object?

for example:

```
Moment('12:16','HH:mm').get('minutes') //should result in '16'
```

I can't find anything like that in documentation though...

Comment: moment().minutes(); // Number

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please try the following:-

```
Moment('12:16','HH:mm').minutes();
```

**UPDATE:**

Second option here - use `format('mm')`. It will return `'16'` in a string format.

Moment.js has documented `minutes()` function in [link](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/).

P.S. A piece of advice for the future - be more detailed in your question. Probably, you have some use-case in your code that you want to solve. In case if people have a description of your case they could help you to solve you case maybe in a more elegant way.

Have a nice day! Be kind and mark the answer that was useful for you as the right one!

Answer (score 8):

```
moment().minute(); // Number
moment().seconds(); // Number
```

Document : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/

```js
var now = moment().minutes();
alert(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```